# AWS S3 and Bandwidth billing by Cognito user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I Want to build an serverless application that can store simple objects in S3, manage the user Login using AWS Cognito, and make the pricing pay-as-you-go for the user, (Charge the user for the Bandwidth and S3 storage used monthly)

I could not find documentation that could help me, so my questions is:

> Is it possible to get information about the bandwidth and S3 storage
>   used by a specific Cognito user directly from aws?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add up the size of objects owned by a Cognito user, so I think the storage part is possible. While, I don't think there is a possible way to get the bandwidth stats.

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc, to identify the resource owned by a user i have to use the federated  user id?